# Gson not deserializing JSON data

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I am trying to get some weather information from Yahoo APIs. This is my JSON:

[JSON](https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22Rhodes%2C%20Gr%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys%22)

This is my DTO:

```
public class forecast implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -520652416977871134L;
private String text;
private String high;
private String day;
private String code;
private String low;
private String date;

public forecast() {
}


public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public String getHigh() {
    return high;
}

public void setHigh(String high) {
    this.high = high;
}

public String getDay() {
    return day;
}

public void setDay(String day) {
    this.day = day;
}

public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}

public String getLow() {
    return low;
}

public void setLow(String low) {
    this.low = low;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ClassPojo [text = " + text + ", high = " + high + ", day = "
            + day + ", code = " + code + ", low = " + low + ", date = "
            + date + "]";
}
}
```

I am only interested for the `forecast` element.

When I try to read the data de-serialized into my DTO all of them are null. I sense that I have not formatted my DTO properly.

Also, what Is the right way to map JSON to POJOs?

EDIT: this is my code for deserializing

```
    String endpoint = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20"
            + "where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22Rhodes%2C%20Gr%22)&"
            + "format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys";
    try {
        URL endpointURL = new URL(endpoint);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) endpointURL
                .openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
        reader.setLenient(true);
        forecast response = new Gson().fromJson(reader,
                forecast.class);
        Log.d("forecast", response.toString());//override toString() to return all the values of the object
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Where's your code for using GSON?

Comment: Added the code where I use GSON

Comment: How are you invoking `Gson`? Since `forecast` is one of the inner elements and it's an array of objects you cannot just ignore everything else and get one `forecast` instance directly from the JSON.

Comment: How should I create my DTO then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON (which you get from Yahoo) is very complex. So it can not be easily mapped to simple POJO (but you still can write huge POJO that contains fields for all corresponding nested JSON elements).

But it is possible to parse and extract specific elements from JSON.

The code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String endpoint = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20"
            + "where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22Rhodes%2C%20Gr%22)&"
            + "format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys";
    try {
        URL endpointURL = new URL(endpoint);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) endpointURL
                .openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
        reader.setLenient(true);

        JsonElement forecastSubObject = new JsonParser().parse(reader).
                getAsJsonObject().get("query").
                getAsJsonObject().get("results").
                getAsJsonObject().get("channel").
                getAsJsonObject().get("item").
                getAsJsonObject().get("forecast");  

        System.out.println(forecastSubObject.toString());   

        List<forecast> forecasts = (List<forecast>)new Gson().fromJson(forecastSubObject, List.class);

        System.out.println("forecast : " + forecasts);
        System.out.println("first forecast: " + forecasts.get(0));      
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Using `JsonParser` you can walk through elements (by theirs names). When 'forecast' element is reached corresponding string is extracted. Then it parsed as usual object and mapped to list of your forecast POJO.

Generally speaking mapping to/from JSON is very wide sphere. Different libraries provide different ways for achieving this (from simple and dirty to complex but reliable).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @flaz14. Let me try this and get back to you.

Comment: Well, I only need the forecast element so I tried to `getAsJsonObject().get("forecast") but still the object is `null`. Any idea on this? I've also noticed that the `forecast` is an array, but the GSON api does not agree with me throwing an exception saying that this is not an array.

Comment: I've edited code. So the whole array of forecast POJO is loaded `List<forecast> forecasts = (List<forecast>)new Gson().fromJson(forecastSubObject, List.class);` loads this array. Then any desired item can be taken from `forecasts` list.

Comment: The logic of Gson library is something like this: take element named "query" from the root of JSON, then take element named "results" from the "query" and so on, until we reach element named "item" (some kind of nested search, by you should define full path to desired element). "forecast" item is nested in "item". So we peek the former. In case of `getAsJsonObject().get("forecast")` loads "forecast" element from the root of JSON, cannot find it and then returns null.